# Where do Wikis using MediaWiki Software Store Their Articles?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

Where and how do wikis that use the MediaWiki software store their articles?

Answer (score 11):

In a MySQL database, typically.

Nowadays MediaWiki also supports other databases, such as PostgreSQL. For details, read the "Database server" section [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installation_requirements).

Edit: as to *how* MediaWiki stores the articles, see [Manual:Database layout](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout) for much details, such as a [diagram](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/File:Mediawiki-database-schema.png) of the database schema and the [SQL](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/maintenance/tables.sql?view=markup) for creating the tables.

Comment: Mediawiki does now (mostly) support SQLLite, so it could also be stored in a file. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SQLite

Comment: **MariaDB** is slowly replacing MySQL as the typical MediaWiki database. Wikipedia, for example, [is migrating its production databases to MariaDB](http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikitech-l/2012-December/064994.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from page 
left join revision on page_id=rev_page
left join text on rev_text_id =old_id 
limit 100;
```

This sql-query shows which table and how MediaWiki software store their articles.

Answer (score 0):

In a MySQL database. I've tried using PostgreSQL but encountered a Mediawiki bug in searching text.